# This correct this demonstration of Number theory (binomial Expressions)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, translation-request

$$\\$$Em minha apostila tem as demonstrações dos seguintes lemas:$$\text{Lema (*): Sejam $a,m,n,q,r\in\mathbb{N}$ com $a\geq2$ tais que $m=nq+r$ then:}\\(a^m-1,a^n+1)=\begin{cases}(a^n+1,a^r-1)& \text{Se}\;q\;\text{é par}\\ (a^n+1,a^r+1)& \text{Se}\;q\;\text{é ímpar}\end{cases}$$
Outro lema: $$\text{Lema (**):}\;\;(x,y)=x\Longleftrightarrow x\mid y$$

> A questão é a seguinte: Seja $(M_n)_n$ a sequência definida por $M_n=2^n-1$. Mostre que $3\mid M_n$ se, e somente se, $n$ é par.
>   $$$$Demonstração:
>
> $\Longrightarrow$
>
> $3\mid 2^n-1\underbrace{\Longrightarrow}_{**} (2^n-1,3)=3\Longrightarrow (2^n-1,2+1)=3$
>
> Pelo lema (*), e sabendo que $\underbrace{n=1n+0}_{m=nq+r}$ temos que:
>
> Se $n$ é ímpar, então $(2^n-1,2+1)=(2+1,2^0+1)=(3,2)=1\neq3$ então temos que se $n$ é ímpar $3\nmid 2^n-1$.
>
> Se $n$ é par, então $(2^n-1,2+1)=(2+1,2^0-1)=(3,0)=3$ então temos que se $n$ é par, então $3\mid 2^n-1$.
>
> Logo, se $3\mid 2^n-1\Longrightarrow n$ é par. $\;\;\;\;\;\Box$
>
> $\Longleftarrow$
>
> Tendo que $n$ é par, então $n=2k$ para algum $k\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> Vamos mostrar então que  $3\mid 2^{2k}-1\Longrightarrow 3\mid4^k-1\;\;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Demonstrando por indução:
>
> I) $k=0$$$3\mid 4^0-1\Longrightarrow 3\mid 0\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{OK}$$
>
> II) Hipótese: $$3\mid4^k-1$$
>
> III) Tese: $$3\mid4^{k+1}-1$$
>
> Demonstração:
>
> $$3\mid4^{k+1}-1\\3\mid4^k4-1\\3\mid4^k4-1-3+3\\3\mid4^k4-4+3\\3\mid4(4^k-1)+3$$ Por Hipótese de indução $3\mid4^k-1$ então $3\mid4(4^k-1)$ e como $3\mid 3$ logo $3\mid 4^{k+1}-1$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\;\;\;\;\;\;\Box$

Comment: could it be that something strange with the formulation of the title?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi I do not speak English, perhaps my translator

Comment: Hi Marcel.  "pair" number should be "even" number.  Best regards.

Comment: @JohnM I do not understand your comment

Comment: @marcelolpjunior you do need to adivse with a native speaker in math. Your mats problem looks quite delicate but language does not allow to help properly.

Comment: I mean that there is a minor translation issue.  "pair" should be "even".  Anyway, your proof looks basically correct.  Maybe the only improvement (toward the end, after "Show") would be to reverse the order of the steps, i.e. write $3|4(4^k-1)+3$ first, and then conclude with $3|4^{k+1}-1$.  That way you are ending with your conclusion.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi I'll edit it to Portuguese and ask someone to translate.

Comment: excellent then the audience can surely help.

Comment: @JohnM Tank you very much, edited.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the result can be proved in detail in a couple of lines.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do it to me, please, that I may see otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

We use congruence notation. Note that $2\equiv -1\pmod{3}$.

If $n$ is even, then $2^n-1\equiv (-1)^n-1\equiv 1-1\equiv  0\pmod{3}$. Thus $3$ divides $2^n-1$.

If $n$ is odd, then $2^n-1\equiv (-1)^n-1\equiv -2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Thus $3$ does not divide $2^n-1$.

**Remark:** Your proof is correct. It is longer than necessary.

One can prove the result in various other ways. For example, recall that if $n$ is odd, then 
$$x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+\cdots+1).$$
Putting $x=2$, we find that $3$ divides $2^n+1$, and therefore the remainder when you divide $2^n-1$ by $3$ is $2$.

Now we deal with even $n$. If $n$ is even and $\gt 0$, then $n-1$ is odd. Therefore by the previous calculation $2^{n-1}-1$ has shape $3m+2$. But then 
$$2^n-1=2(2^{n-1}-1)+1=2(3m+2)-1=6m+3,$$
 so $2^n-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Magic modular arithmetic. Interesting. But not yet studied this content. Thank you. (Just do not quite understand)